# Change @ to $ in RazorEngine

Tags: c#, .net, template-engine, razorengine, razorgenerator

Can we change the @ to $ in the [razormachine](https://github.com/jlamfers/RazorMachine) 
As my template is going to contain a lot of @

Comment: Are you going to use @  for displaying email adresses?

Comment: hi. were you able to get this to work?

Comment: Not yet @justelouise